# How to delete documents with 1 call across multiple cores using Solr?

Tags: solr

I am using 6 cores, which make up the totality of my index (8 million documents, spread across 6 cores).  If I want to delete a document (say, deleteById or deleteByQuery), it seems that I have to make 6 delete calls, because I never know which core the particular document is in.  Is this correct?

When I search, I can give the search a 'shards' parameter, and Solr will search across all of the cores.  This deoesn't seem to be true when deleting.

Is there a way to delete documents with one call across multiple cores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could enable the [shard DocTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DocTransformers#A.5Bshard.5D) to return the shard where the document was found during a query. By leveraging this you could do a query for the doc(s) that you want to delete, get the shard id (or core in your case) from the results and send the delete command to appropriate core. Granted this would be an extra query at the beginning, but you would then only need to make one delete request for each document as opposed to one for each core.

The documentation is a little spare on setting this up, so I did some digging and I think the following should be added to your solrconfig.xml file to enable this:

```
     <transformer name="shard" 
         class="org.apache.solr.response.transform.ShardAugmenterFactory"/>
```

From looking at source for the [ShardAugmenterFactory](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_2/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/response/transform/ShardAugmenterFactory.java?view=markup) it will detect if shards are being used in the request and enable the shard output in the response.

Comment: Alas sir, after some experimentation, I see that this is a 4.0 feature.  I'm using Solr 3.6 until we can get our index up to a newer version that Solr 4.x can handle.

Comment: Just an update for those who might come across this.   I updated our environment to Solr 4.x, and this answer IS correct.  It works.